# (Be full of / Have a lot of) (needs / demands)

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, expressions, phrases, sentence-choice

I was wondering what combination sounds more idiomatic here in my example?

> - Children .................. So, forward-looking parents would better make sure whether they can fulfill their needs and meet their demands or not. Then they can make a decision about having a child.

**a.** are full of needs 
**b.** have a lot of needs 
**c.** are full of demands 
**d.** have a lot of demands

I see nothing the matter with all those cases, but they are all direct translations from my mother tongue. I have no clue if they are natural and idiomatic in English as well.

I was wondering if there is any more natural way to imply the same message in this case.

Comment: They are all grammatically correct and sound natural to me.

Comment: For which dialect are you speaking @randomhead?

Comment: Native AmE speaker.

Comment: "*Children are needy*" and "*Children are demanding...*" are natural and more idiomatic ways of expressing the same thing.

Comment: "*...make sure + whether...or not*" is the only unnatural English in your example.

Comment: I just beed to use the structure "full of..." here @gotube or at least "have a lot of...".

Comment: Why do you need to use those structures?

Comment: The way a specific sentence should be said in a story regarding a woman who's going to introduce herself @gotube. Just in order to avoid sounding like a sexist, I changed the whole matter substituting "children" for "women". That's it.

Comment: @A-friend It makes a big difference that you're talking about women and not children. Any sentence that begins, "Women are full of..." is going to come across as sexist.

Comment: Then may I ask you what would be the correct answer when it comes to women as my original question was based on them @gotube. That would be truly helpful.

Comment: @A-friend Any generalization about women that is arguably true about men as well ("men are full of needs") will be taken as sexist in most English-speaking parts of the world. But my job isn't to prevent you from offending -- it's to help you offend while using correct grammar! What did you replace with "parents"?

Comment: Thank you very much @gotube. "**Women are full of needs and demands** a successful husband is someone who can fulfill their needs and meet their demands." Does it sound natural to you?

Comment: @A-friend If you put a period or semicolon between "demands" and "a", then yes, the grammar is good and it sounds natural enough. I'd need a full context to say if the style is right.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically they're all fine, but needs and demands aren't exactly the same thing. Needs = food, water, baby powder, and so on. Demands = those things + the latest iPhone, a bigger room, and so on. Which are you referring to?

"a lot of" sounds neutral. "full of" sounds a tiny bit more informal.

Comment: Actually I mean both.

Comment: If you mean both, I'd lean towards "demands".

Comment: Then how about both "needs and demands" @Sabrina?